# Jackson serialization of abstract interface

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm working with a framework that performs Java Jackson serialization of class `Config` with a field `supplier` that is an abstract interface `Supplier<T>`. The interfaces below are defined in the framework so I cannot change/add the annotations.

```
public interface Supplier<T> {
    T get();
}

public interface Calculator {
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Config extends Serializable {
  private Supplier<Calculator> supplier;
}
```

I have a concrete implementation of `Supplier`:

```
class MySupplier implements Supplier {
   @Override Calculator get() { return ...; }
}
```

When I serialize an instance of `Config` into JSON the supplier field is serialized without class information. From what I understand this is because the field declaration is abstract. As a result during deserialization Jackson doesn't know how to instantiate `supplier` field.

```
"config" : {
 ...
 "supplier" : { }
 ...
}
```

How can I force my implementation of the `Supplier` interface to add class name information into generated JSON to allow proper deserialization? I don't have access to the code that performs serialization and deserialization, I can only manipulate my implementation of `Supplier`.

Comment: Do you have an access to `Jackson`'s `ObjectMapper`? Many frameworks allow to customise serialisation process. I am not sure you can do much without customising it.

Comment: @MichałZiober yes I do have access to ObjectMapper. Is there a way to make serialization specific to my implementation via this object?

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem? Did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 0):

`Jackson` allows to configure third party classes using feature called `MixIn`. For more information read:

1. [Jackson Mixin to the Rescue](https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue)
2. [Jackson Mix-In Annotations](https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mix-in-annotations)

You need to specify two new interface which will allow you to add annotations for other classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MySupplier.class, name = "MySupplier")})
interface SupplierAnnotations {
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyCalculator.class, name = "MyCalculator"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = HisCalculator.class, name = "HisCalculator") }
)
interface CalculatorAnnotations {
}
```

Now, you have to inform `ObjectMapper` about your new classes. You can do that in this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Calculator.class, CalculatorAnnotations.class);
mapper.addMixIn(Supplier.class, SupplierAnnotations.class);
```

Everything you need to do is to list sub types for `Suplier` and `Calculator` interfaces.